# Could not migrate to Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I decided to use Room in my current application.
Find out that there are no type for one column in current schema and Room produce `IllegalStateException` on migration.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle item.
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='item', columns={optional_modifiers=Column{a_type=Column{name='a_type', type='BLOB', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}...}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='item', columns={optional_modifiers=Column{a_type=Column{name='a_type', type='', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}...}
```

Sql script of the table creation:

```
"create table item ("
                " id text primary key," +
                " a_type, "
//...
                ")
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String?,
    val a_type: String? // actually I used several types, but none of them is worked
)
```

Are there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you please share your new entity class & old schema as well?

Comment: Error is indicating that data type mismatch happened in your migration.

Comment: @Pinakin yes, I see that it is type mismatch. But there are no "empty" type in room

Comment: Share me class annotated with @Entity

Comment: Can you please share your Entity class annotated with @Entity ?

Comment: @Pinakin updated

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a way around this ?

Comment: @RaickyDerwent I've posted my own answer

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov Thanks. I ended up doing something similar. I was hoping there was a way around this because my DB is large, but I guess not.

Comment: Check bellow answer. It has complete description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245898/3073945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't allow to edit schema. So the only possible way is create the new table with correct columns info, move data to it, delete old table.

Here is the example of the code that I used

```
        database?.execSQL("create table table_name_tmp ( " +
            " id text not null primary key"
            ")")
        database?.execSQL("""
            insert into table_name_tmp (id)

            select id
            from table_name
            """)
        database?.execSQL("drop table table_name")
        database?.execSQL("alter table table_name_tmp rename to table_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make modification to your class annotated with @Entity as below.

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class Item(
   @PrimaryKey
   val id: String?,
   @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
   val a_type: String?
   )
```

This will work, because from error it is visible that your old db schema is having name='a_type', type='BLOB', so you need to add @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB) this will instruct room to consider data type of "a_type" as BLOB.

Recently it comes to my attention that @ColumnInfo also provide "UNDEFINED" as a type Affinity  so with that you can now declare your table field without any type.[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ColumnInfo.html)

please try updated changes in your project.

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class Item(
@PrimaryKey
val id: String?,
@ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.UNDEFINED)
val a_type: String?
)
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work. My old db schema is having type `` (empty). See last line in error message

Comment: Provided solution based on error. Your error is indicating that your previous db schema is having blob for a_type where your new schema is having empty type for a_type.

Comment: Can you please let me know room version you used ?