# Room Persistence Library: Weird Error during migration

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room

I am scratching my head with this error. I couldn't find any answer so far. I have old database which I am migrating to Persistence Room library. However whenever I do migration, I am getting following error,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle.
```

Code I am using is as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName = ROUTE_TABLE)
public class RouteData {

    static final String ROUTE_TABLE = "name";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "col1")
    private String col1;
    //Other columns with exactly same as 'col1' just different names
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

For migration,

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), MyData.class, DATABASE_NAME)
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_LATEST)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() 
            .build();

private static final Migration MIGRATION_LATEST = new Migration(9, 10) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Log.i("Tag" , "Migration Started");
        //Migration logic
        //Log.i("Tag" , "Migration Ended");
    }
};
```

When I run program. I get "Migration Ended" log in my LogCat but when I am trying access database again, it is giving me following error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle xxx.
                                                                              Expected:
                                                                             TableInfo{name='name', columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ....}, foreignKeys=[]}
                                                                              Found:
                                                                             TableInfo{name='name', columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ....}, foreignKeys=[]}
```

I have no idea where where this "INTEGER" is coming. I tried uninstalling, invalidating cache and any other closely related solution. Any idea what is going on? It works perfectly fine if you freshly install app. Error is coming up only after migration. According to my log cat, all migration steps seems to be completed but it is still showing migration not handled properly.

Comment: Could you add your model before the migration?

Comment: @JoséCarlos, which model ?

Comment: your RouteData class

Comment: @SnehPandya  Thank you for showing interest in helping me. However recently found out the real reason, please check answer :)

Comment: @JoséCarlos Thank you for showing interest in helping me. However recently found out the real reason, please check answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Room Database Migration doesnt properly handle ALTER TABLE migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372036/room-database-migration-doesnt-properly-handle-alter-table-migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help me, however I have finally found the answer after days of frustrating debugging. In my app manifest auto backup was on,

> android:allowBackup="true"

So while trying out various databases, google was actually backing up my any newly created databases and their structure and restoring them automatically when I was reinstalling app. Hence I was getting this wired error. Once I switch of auto backup `android:allowBackup="false"` and reinstall app, I can test migration properly.

My suggestion for all developers in future encountering such problem, **SWITCH OFF** auto backup while development. You can switch it on once you have tested your migration.

Comment: Or before reinstalling the old version, clear you app data. `Settings > Apps > your app > Storage > Clear Data`

Comment: @StuStirling, this did not work in my case. Google was always setting my database to previous state while installing new version. Hence that was giving problem while migration.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your migration script is bellow:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle xxx.
                                                                              Expected:
                                                                             TableInfo{name='name', columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ....}, foreignKeys=[]}
                                                                              Found:
                                                                             TableInfo{name='name', columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ....}, foreignKeys=[]}
```

Here, in your Entity Class you have :

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "col1")
    private String col1;
```

but in your migration query you may be adding `col1` as `INTEGER`

From your error :

**Expected** :

```
columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}
```

**Found** :

```
columns={col1=Column{name='col1', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}
```

**Solution**: change your migration query like :

**ALTER TABLE 'YOUR_TABLE' ADD COLUMN 'col1' TEXT**

It will solve your problem.

Thanks :)